# Installation of haskell-chart fails due to gtk-0.14.2 build error

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, gtk2hs

I'm trying to install haskell-chart from [here](https://github.com/timbod7/haskell-chart) (github), I clone it, install *stack*, ran *stack setup* (it installs GHC successfully), but then I ran *make* that fails with the messages:

```
...
Chart-cairo-1.8: copy/register
Chart-diagrams-1.8: copy/register
Progress: 4/6
--  While building package gtk-0.14.2 using:
      /tmp/stack4807/gtk-0.14.2/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.5.0/setup/setup --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.5.0 build --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
...

[ 22 of 209] Compiling Graphics.UI.Gtk.Embedding.Plug ( .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.5.0/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/Embedding/Plug.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.5.0/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/Embedding/Plug.o )

    /tmp/stack4807/gtk-0.14.2/Graphics/UI/Gtk/Embedding/Plug.chs:120:6:
        Couldn't match expected type ‘CUInt’
                    with actual type ‘Maybe DrawWindow’
        In the first argument of ‘gtk_plug_new’, namely...
```

Stack version is 1.1.2 x86_64 hpack-0.14.1, LTS Haskell 5.18 (ghc-7.10.3). What can I do with this errors?

Comment: Have you tried it with a more recent LTS resolver?

Comment: I have tried lts-3.22, that [should](https://www.stackage.org/lts-3.22/docs) use gtk-0.13.9, but get the same errors about gtk-0.14.2. I new in haskell and stack but stack with lts-3.22 asked me for another version of ghc (that means that stack really uses lts-3.22).

Comment: More _recent_ resolver conflicts with requirements of haskell-chart dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

In order to build haskell-chart from github sources on linux one should replace in `stack.yaml`

```
flags:
    gtk:
        have-quartz-gtk: true
```

with

```
flags: {}
```

because Linux don't use Quartz flag `have-quartz-gtk`, and Quartz is not needed to build gtk (Windows also do not use Quartz).

Comment: thanks for the answer. I added it to the [github issue](https://github.com/timbod7/haskell-chart/issues/163#issuecomment-318504387)

Answer (score 0):

Using **brew** I upgraded gtk+ from version 2.24.25 to 2.24.30 and installed the latest version of XQuartz (version 2.7.9 - I couldn't determine which version I had originally installed.)

With these changes I was able to successfully build the project with `stack build`.

Specific commands:

```
$ brew cask install xquartz --force
$ brew upgrade gtk
```

Comment: Actually this flag is already is in the stack.yaml. Also`stack build --flag gtk:have-quartz-gtk` leads to the same errors.

Comment: My OS is Arch Linux, not mac.

Comment: I upgrade gtk from 2.24.28 to 2.24.30 by Arch package manager, but then `stack build` leads to exactly the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you don't actually have to use gtk. There are two rendering backend for the chart library - one based upon [cairo](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cairo) from gtk2hs the other on the [diagrams](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/diagrams) library. The cairo backend is significantly faster, whereas the diagrams backend is pure haskell, and hence is easier to build.

By default, both backends are built, but you can build just the core library and the diagrams backend with:

`stack build ./chart ./chart-diagrams`

Comment: Actually, I'm using _cairo_ now for PDF output. I follow your [previous suggestion](https://github.com/timbod7/haskell-chart/issues/138) and make my figures as a "package" with its own stack.yaml and cabal files. I see now that I don't have to use gtk but I just wanted to look inside the source code, maybe make some changes etc. and learn Haskell by this.